# SharePoint 2010: The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: sharepoint-2010

here's my Javascript code to retrieve items is a SharePoint 2010 (SP) list.

```
var clientContextPath = "/path/site1";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(clientContextPath);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list); 
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
...
```

However, if I want to retrieve from other site i.e.

```
var clientContextPath = "/path/site2";
```

then same code generates exception " The security validation for this page is invalid". This is within the same Domain, so it's not something to do with XSS.

Interestingly, same code works fine when I use another Site

```
var clientContextPath = "/path/site3";
```

Please help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the page you are running your javascript has this control on it:

```
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />
```

The FormDigest add a security token inside your page based on user, site and time. Once the page is posted back the security token is validated. Once the security token is generated it’s valid for a configurable amount of time.

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-for.html

**UPDATE**: if the above does not work, try this just before you execute the query:

```
function CustomUpdateFormDigest()
{
    if(window._spPageContextInfo != null)
    {
        var $v_2 = window._spPageContextInfo;
        var $v_3 = $v_2.webServerRelativeUrl;
        var $v_4 = window._spFormDigestRefreshInterval;
        UpdateFormDigest($v_3, $v_4);
    }
}
CustomUpdateFormDigest();
```

This worked for me when my only options was to turn off page validation.

**UPDATE 2:**

Seems like you probably hit a sharepoint bug. Maybe try to go through the Cumulative Updates, or as a last resort turn page validation off, just make sure you understand the security implications of this option

Comment: I tried above solution, but didn't work. I still get security validation is invalid exception. Besides this doesn't explain why the code works fine for other sites and not this specific one.

Comment: Check my update, about some working and some not. it happens quite often with sharepoint.

Comment: thanks Luis, unfortunately your other solution doesn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this solution, and I was sure it was not going to work but...it did! Basically it's an Ajax request to gather the new token from SharePoint.

```
$.ajax({
        url: projecturl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue);

            EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharingDialog', function () { DisplaySharingDialog(projecturl) });

        },
        error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where does this code go? The same Js file that's doing the query?

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way

```
UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval)
```

This is native method is sharepoint. Just add this method before calling ajax request or executeQueryAsync().

Source: http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript