# Sharepoint error: Enable-SPFeature : The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

When I try to deploy the project via PowerShell, **PS** proceed the **"Enable-SPFeature"** operation, 
then it prints the error message below:

> Enable-SPFeature : The security validation for this page is invalid.
>   Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your
>   operation again.
>       At E:\Demo\DemoProject\DemoProject\scripts\utility.ps1:315 char:19
>       + Enable-SPFeature <<<<  -identity $id -url $url -confirm:$false
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etEnableFeature:SPCmdletEnableFeature)
>   [Enable-SPFeature], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature

Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2010: The security validation for this page is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092108/sharepoint-2010-the-security-validation-for-this-page-is-invalid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever we update any list item, list or `SPWeb` instance you may get  "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again". This is because of some security validation while updating the modification to the content database, so, in order to escape from that exception we have to make `AllowUnsafeUpdates` property of the `SPWeb` instance as true.

```
SPWeb oWeb = new SPWeb();

oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

`AllowUnsafeUpdates` property is used to Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether to allow updates to the database as a result of a GET request or without requiring a security validation. `SPSite` class also has this property.